# docker run command not taking the --env variable placeholder value

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I am trying to run a docker image with the below command :

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 shoppingms:latest --env shopping-service.configserverurl=http://shopping-config:8888/ --env shopping-service.eureka.url=http://shopping-eureka:4444/
```

I have set the host name in `/etc/hosts` file to point to the docker IP. However it is throwing `UnknownHost` error.

And when I am giving the IP address instead, then also it takes the default value from bootstrap.yaml, throwing the same error.

**Bootstrap.yaml**

```
    spring:
       cloud:
         config:
           uri: ${shopping-service.configserverurl:http://shopping-config:8888}
           fail-fast: true
           retry:
             maxAttempts: 20
```

However when I give the actual docker host IP in the placeholder above, it is running fine.

**Working case :**

```
uri: ${shopping-service.configserverurl:http://<Docker-Host>:8888}
```

Why it is not able to parse the actual placeholder IP value from the docker run command ?

Comment: Everything after the image name is taken as the command to run; the `--env` option needs to be _before_ the image name.

Comment: @DavidMaze : Thanks. Its working that way